# Git-annex installation on macOS BigSur11.6

Tags: homebrew, macos-big-sur, git-annex, datalad

I am trying to install git-annex using homebrew. After installing brew, when i typed

> brew install git-annex
> in the commandline, it showed
> "git-annex: no bottle available!".
> I also want to download datalad, after following the steps on datalad handbook, it appeared the same problem as installing git-annex
> brew install datalad
> "Error: datalad: no bottle available!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-annex` and `datalad` don't have bottles for M1 Macs right now. The following pages will say "Apple Silicon Big Sur" under the section "Bottle (binary package) installation support" when the bottles are added, but at the time of writing, they only have bottles for Intel Big Sur.

- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-annex
- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/datalad

Maybe try running `brew install --build-from-source git-annex` and see if it installs successfully on your machine.

Comment: That's really helpful! I have tried installing from source code, but it seems not working properly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As of now (and some time already), there are bottles for both git-annex and datalad for Big Sur on M1.

See:

- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-annex
- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/datalad